# How do I use the data that was called when working with an API?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api

I am trying to use an api for the first time, and I need to use the data that was called. When I run my script, I get a `<Response [200]>` so my code is successful, but how do I view and use the information that was called. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is how you request the api,

```
r = requests.get("api")
```

In this way you'll have a plain text response.

```
print(r.text)
```

You can also get json output by doing so

```
print(r.json())
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `requests`.

```
response = requests.get("some url")

response.status_code # get the status code

json_response = response.json() # convert response to json
print(json_response) # you can see dictionary-like structure
print(json_response["arbitrary"]) # you can access data just like normal dictionary
```

[Here's `requests` documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)